# Is there a way to ignore the "fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve LABEL" error during the boot?

Tags: linux, raid, boot, fsck

We have a file-cluster on servers with multiple disks, and we have created a software RAID1 over boot and / partitions, planning that if a single disk goes down, we still will be able to boot and serve data from the remaining disks.

The problem is that when one of disks missing, the server when booting up, displays the following error:

fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve LABEL

LABEL is one of the missing disks partition - boot and / RAID1 partitions seem to work fine.

Is there any configuration to ignore these errors, and just bring the server online? So if there one of disks missing, the server will ignore any errors, and just will continue booting?

Comment: Why would you want to ignore an error that reminds you that your array is degraded? Why not just, say, fix the problem instead?

Comment: Point is that it more easy/faster to re-provision the server for us, but we do want to safely migrate the data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the partition in question is marked for fsck to check on boot. It is the sixth field (the last one) in /etc/fstab, referred to as "pass" or "fs_passno". If this field is present, and is not 0, it indicates the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot time.

So, either remove that column from the fstab file, or replace it with 0, like this:

```
LABEL=the_label    /the/mount/point    ext3    defaults
```

Comment: Thanks, we have eventually re-provisioned the server, but I will keep your solution in mind for the next time.